# Why a beta distribution with the parameters $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$ as a prior is bad

Tags: probability, bayesian

what happened if I define a beta distribution with $\alpha=0$ and $\beta=0$ as a prior? in other words if $p(\theta) \varpropto \frac{1}{\theta(1-\theta)}$.

Thanks

Comment: Does this density integrate to 1?

Comment: What is the constant of proportionality? It often does not matter, but in this case it might...

Comment: this is the explain from the note, which I am not quit understand.Assume we observe a single toss. If $x = 1$, the prior squeezes the mass extremely towards unity, and correspondingly towards zero when we observe $x = 0$. This means that on the basis of a single observation we believe the future observations to be analogous in value. $\theta$ is probability that $x=1$

Comment: You should probably post the whole note. A good prior is highly dependent on the context - for example, if you're estimating the parameter of a Bernoulli($\theta$) distribution with mean square error criterion, one may argue $\theta$ being uniform[0,1] is not a good prior due to the structure of the posterior mean, leading to the idea of Jeffrey's priors, for example. By definition though, a beta distribution has positive parameters, so I'm not sure what you're getting at here, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A prior of the form of a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=\beta=0$ is 'bad' in the sense that it is what is referred to as an improper prior. In some circumstances, it leads to an improper posterior distribution, which of course is undesirable. For example, the Beta distribution is a conjugate prior to a bernoulli likelihood, where the posterior is a Beta($\alpha + \sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \beta + n - \sum_{i=1}^nx_i$) distribution. Note that if you have $\alpha=\beta=0$ and either only successes ($x_i=1\forall i$) or failures ($x_i=0\forall i$), one of these two parameters in the posterior is going to be $0$, and hence you will have a posterior that is improper. Improper priors also severely complicate model comparisons.